# Avoiding for-loop by using QuerySelector inside of a table

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a list of the multiple records per row from table with **querySelectorAll** but I have tried by one way but got stuck inside a multiple for-loop.

I want to know if there is a more appropriate way to this specific problem with the querySelectorAll function?

What I have tried so far:

Html extracted so far from: `var innerT = t2[i].cells;`

```js
t2 = document.querySelectorAll('.flexible.block_xp-report-table tbody tr');
for (var i = 0; i < t2.length; i++) {
  var innerT = t2[i].cells; //the generated HTML is from this steps
  for (var j = 0; j < innerT.length; j++) {
    var innerT1 = innerT[j].cells;
    for (var k = 0; k < innerT1.length; k++) {
      console.log(innerT1[k])
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" class="flexible block_xp-report-table" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596535723450_172">
  <thead id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596535723450_189">
    <tr id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596535723450_188">
      <th class="header c0" scope="col" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596535723450_187">
        S.N
      </th>
      <th class="header c1" scope="col" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596535723450_198">
        Name
      </th>
      <th class="header c2" scope="col">
        Level
      </th>
      <th class="header c3" scope="col">
        Point
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596535723450_171">
    <tr class="" id="block_xp_report_r0">
      <td class="cell c0" id="block_xp_report_r0_c0">
        <a href="http://test.com.np/user/view.php?id=2157&amp;course=103">Image 1</a>
      </td>
      <td class="cell c1" id="block_xp_report_r0_c1">
        <a href="http://test.com.np/user/view.php?id=2157&amp;course=103" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596532113936_188">John</a>
      </td>
      <td class="cell c2" id="block_xp_report_r0_c2">6</td>
      <td class="cell c3" id="block_xp_report_r0_c3">
        <div class="block_xp-xp">
          <div class="pts">6,414</div>
          <div class="sign sign-sup">xp</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="block_xp_report_r1">
      <td class="cell c0" id="block_xp_report_r1_c0">
        <a href="http://test.com.np/user/view.php?id=2158&amp;course=103">Image 1</a>
      </td>
      <td class="cell c1" id="block_xp_report_r1_c1">
        <a href="http://test.com.np/user/view.php?id=2158&amp;course=103" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596532113936_188">John</a> -- -- I the value of href only

      </td>
      <td class="cell c2" id="block_xp_report_r1_c2">6</td> -- I need this number only
      <td class="cell c3" id="block_xp_report_r1_c3">
        <div class="block_xp-xp">
          <div class="pts">6,414</div> -- I need this number only
          <div class="sign sign-sup">xp</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr> --- this tr will go expanding ---
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to get `text` from the `td`? Please share your complete `table` `structure`.

Comment: okay i will update with complete table.

Comment: @Karan updated my post with the table structure and the things I want

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelector` (similar to `querySelectorAll` but return first matching element only) on `html object` also. Thus `t2[i].querySelector('.c1 a')` will return `a` inside `td` which is having `c1` class inside `t2[i]`. Then get `href` value using `.getAttribute('href');`.

Similarly use `t2[i].querySelector('.pts').innerText;` to get `div` with class `pts` inside `t2[i]`. Use `innerText` to get `text` from the `div`.

Try it below.

```js
var t2 = document.querySelectorAll('.flexible.block_xp-report-table tbody tr');
for (var i = 0; i < t2.length; i++) {
  var href = t2[i].querySelector('.c1 a').getAttribute('href');
  console.log(href);
  var pts = t2[i].querySelector('.pts').innerText;
  console.log(pts);
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" class="flexible block_xp-report-table" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596535723450_172">
  <thead id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596535723450_189">
    <tr id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596535723450_188">
      <th class="header c0" scope="col" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596535723450_187">
        S.N
      </th>
      <th class="header c1" scope="col" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596535723450_198">
        Name
      </th>
      <th class="header c2" scope="col">
        Level
      </th>
      <th class="header c3" scope="col">
        Point
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596535723450_171">
    <tr class="" id="block_xp_report_r0">
      <td class="cell c0" id="block_xp_report_r0_c0">
        <a href="http://test.com.np/user/view.php?id=2157&amp;course=103">Image 1</a>
      </td>
      <td class="cell c1" id="block_xp_report_r0_c1">
        <a href="http://test.com.np/user/view.php?id=2157&amp;course=103" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596532113936_188">John</a>
      </td>
      <td class="cell c2" id="block_xp_report_r0_c2">6</td>
      <td class="cell c3" id="block_xp_report_r0_c3">
        <div class="block_xp-xp">
          <div class="pts">6,414</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="" id="block_xp_report_r1">
      <td class="cell c0" id="block_xp_report_r1_c0">
        <a href="http://test.com.np/user/view.php?id=2158&amp;course=103">Image 1</a>
      </td>
      <td class="cell c1" id="block_xp_report_r1_c1">
        <a href="http://test.com.np/user/view.php?id=2158&amp;course=103" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596532113936_188">John</a>
      </td>
      <td class="cell c2" id="block_xp_report_r1_c2">6</td>
      <td class="cell c3" id="block_xp_report_r1_c3">
        <div class="block_xp-xp">
          <div class="pts">6,414</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<body onload="init()">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

    <table class="block_xp-report-table">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="" id="block_xp_report_r0">
                <td class="cell c0" id="block_xp_report_r0_c0">
                    1
                </td>
                <td class="cell c1" id="block_xp_report_r0_c1">
                    <a href="http://test.com.np/user/view.php?id=2157&amp;course=103"
                        id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596532113936_188"
                        data-attribute="-- need to get the href value from here not the name">John</a>
                </td>
                <td class="cell c2" id="block_xp_report_r0_c2" data-attribute="---need to get this text ">6</td>
                <td class="cell c3" id="block_xp_report_r0_c3">
                    <div class="block_xp-xp">
                        <div class="pts" data-attribute="---need to get this text ">6,414</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="" id="block_xp_report_r1">
                <td class="cell c0" id="block_xp_report_r1_c0">
                    <a href="http://test.com.np/user/view.php?id=2158&amp;course=103">Image 1</a>
                </td>
                <td class="cell c1" id="block_xp_report_r1_c1">
                    <a href="http://test.com.np/user/view.php?id=2158&amp;course=103"
                        id="yui_3_17_2_1_1596532113936_188">John</a>
                </td>
                <td class="cell c2" id="block_xp_report_r1_c2">6</td>
                <td class="cell c3" id="block_xp_report_r1_c3">
                    <div class="block_xp-xp">
                        <div class="pts">6,414</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>


    <script>

        function init() {

            const rowIndexes = {

                href: 1,
                text: 2,
                points: 3
            }

            const responses = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.block_xp-report-table tbody tr'))
                .map(res => {



                    const getFor = (elemName) => {
                        return res.querySelectorAll("td")[rowIndexes[elemName]]
                    }


                    return { href: getFor('href').querySelector("a").getAttribute("href"), text: getFor('text').innerText, points: getFor('points').innerText }
                })

            console.log(responses)

          
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Result will be (Assuming table class is block_xp-report-table)

```
[{"href":"http://test.com.np/user/view.php?id=2157&course=103","text":"6","points":"6,414"},{"href":"http://test.com.np/user/view.php?id=2158&course=103","text":"6","points":"6,414"}]
```

Comment: There is no loop , purely functional iteration

Comment: Thank you for you, I like the answer, I miss one slight thing in the question can I have updated the question, just a single div, below the class `.pts`?

Comment: I m outside,typing in mobile.   hope the below works.
                    return { href: getFor('href').querySelector("a").getAttribute("href"), text: getFor('text').innerText, points: getFor('points').queryselector(".pts").innerText }
                })